# NHiberate Joined Subclass Invalid Property

Tags: nhibernate, joined-subclass

I'm trying to work through this issue where the subclass contains a set of properties however two of the properties do not exist in the referenced table.

These two properties exist in an Extension table that has FKs back to the base table. I'm unsure how to modify this xml to support the first joined subclass and addition of another join for the Extension table.

I tried to simply add another joined-subclass for the Extension table, however since the class name was the same, the mapping were invalid.

```
    <joined-subclass name="SESProgramAssociationAggregate.SESProgramAssociation" table="SESProgramAssociation" lazy="false">
  <key>
    <column name="BeginDate" />
    <column name="EOId" />
    <column name="PEOrganizationId" />
    <column name="ProgramName" />
    <column name="ProgramTypeId" />
    <column name="UDI" />
  </key>

  <!-- PK properties -->
  <property name="UDI" column="UDI" type="int" not-null="true" insert="false" />
  <property name="ProgramTypeId" column="ProgramTypeId" type="int" not-null="true" insert="false" />
  <property name="PEOrganizationId" column="PEOrganizationId" type="int" not-null="true" insert="false" />
  <property name="BeginDate" column="BeginDate" type="date" not-null="true" insert="false" />
  <property name="ProgramName" column="ProgramName" type="string" length="60" not-null="true" insert="false" />
  <property name="EOId" column="EOId" type="int" not-null="true" insert="false" />

  <!-- Properties -->
  <property name="Eligibility" column="Eligibility" type="bool" />
  <property name="SESDescriptorId" column="SESDescriptorId" type="int" not-null="true" />
  <property name="SEHoursPerWeek" column="SEHoursPerWeek" type="decimal" />
  <property name="HoursPerWeek" column="HoursPerWeek" type="decimal" />
  <property name="MultiplyD" column="MultiplyD" type="bool" />
  <property name="MFragile" column="MFragile" type="bool" />
  <property name="LastEvalDate" column="LastEvalDate" type="date" />
  <property name="ReviewDate" column="ReviewDate" type="date" />
  <property name="BeginDate" column="BeginDate" type="date" />
  <property name="EndDate" column="EndDate" type="date" />
  <property name="EventCode" column="EventCode" type="int" />
  <property name="WrittenConsentDate" column="WrittenConsentDate" type="date" />

</joined-subclass>
```

The final query that is generated fails because it attempts to reference the EventCode and WrittenConsentDate from the SESProgramAssociation table where they do not exist. They actually exist in the Extension table.

I'm not sure how to modify this xml to point those fields to the Extension table
so the generated query actually pulls them from that table instead of the wrong one. Any help is greatly appreciated, this is my first experience with NHiberate and needless to say, it's not been fun!

After advice from Frédéric, I updated but got this error:

An exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: EdFi.Ods.Entities.NHibernate.Mappings.SqlServer.StudentProgramAssociationBase.hbm.xml(79,8): XML validation error: The element 'joined-subclass' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'join' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'property, many-to-one, one-to-one, component, dynamic-component, properties, any, map, set, list, bag, idbag, array, primitive-array, joined-subclass, loader, sql-insert, sql-update, sql-delete, resultset, query, sql-query' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Answer (score 1):

Your second table should not be mapped as another `joined-subclass`, since it does not match a subclass in your domain model.

It should be mapped either as a standalone `Extension` entity, with the extended entity referencing it as a [`one-to-one`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) related entity.

Or you can use the [`join`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join) mapping for having a single entity in your domain model. But the `join` mapping is not allowed on `subclass`, so you would have to use it on your base class, if you can add to it those properties. Adjusting your pastebin mapping linked in comment:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="Entities.NHibernate" 
                   namespace="Entities.NHibernate.SPAssociationAggregate"
                           default-access="property">

  <!-- Class definition -->
  <class name="SPAssociationBase" table="SPAssociation" lazy="false">
    <!-- Composite primary key -->
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="BeginDate" type="date" />
      <key-property name="OrganizationId" />
      <key-property name="ProgramOrganizationId" />
      <key-property name="ProgramName" length="60" />
      <key-property name="ProgramTypeId" />
      <key-property name="SUSI" />
    </composite-id>

    <!-- Optimistic locking for aggregate root -->
    <version name="LastModifiedDate" type="timestamp" />

    <!-- Transient state detection -->
    <property name="CreateDate" type="DateTime" />

    <!-- Unique Guid-based identifier for aggregate root -->
    <property name="Id" />

    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="EndDate" type="date" />
    <property name="ReasonExitedDescriptorId" />
    <property name="ServedOutsideOfRegularSession" />

    <!-- Collections -->
    <bag name="SPAssociationServices" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false">
      <key>
        <column name="BeginDate" />
        <column name="OrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramOrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramName" />
        <column name="ProgramTypeId" />
        <column name="SUSI" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="SPAssociationServiceForBase" />
    </bag>

    <!-- Extended properties -->
    <join table="SSEPAssociationExtension" optional="true">
      <key>
        <column name="BeginDate" />
        <column name="OrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramOrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramName" />
        <column name="ProgramTypeId" />
        <column name="SUSI" />
      </key>
      <property name="EventCode" />
      <property name="WrittenConsentDate" />
    </join>

    <!-- Derived classes -->
    <joined-subclass name="SESProgramAssociationAggregate.SESProgramAssociation" table="SESProgramAssociation" lazy="false">
      <key>
        <column name="BeginDate" />
        <column name="OrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramOrganizationId" />
        <column name="ProgramName" />
        <column name="ProgramTypeId" />
        <column name="SUSI" />
      </key>

      <!-- Properties -->
      <property name="IdeaEligibility" />
      <property name="DescriptorId" />
      <property name="HoursPerWeek" />
      <property name="SHoursPerWeek" />
      <property name="MultiplyD" />
      <property name="MFragile" />
      <property name="LastEvaluationDate" type="date" />
      <property name="ReviewDate" type="date" />
      <property name="BeginDate" type="date" />
      <property name="EndDate" type="date" />
      <property name="EventCode" />
      <property name="WrittenConsentDate" type="date" />
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Side notes:

- Better avoid composite key if possible. Or map them as [component](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html#components-compositeid), override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for them, ...
- There is no need duplicating property names as column names if they are the same. And most property types can be inferred from the underlying class by NHibernate. If they match, better not bloat your mapping by specifying their type in mapping. (So I have left only string lengths in my example above, and date type, since there is no precise match between .Net date & time types and SQL ones.)
- It is strange to "remap" your primary key as properties in subclass. You should inherit those properties from base class `<id>`, and so you should not have any need to map them again in the joined subclass.
- Disabling `lazy` loading is not an usual practice with NHibernate. Lazy loading with NHibernate can benefit of batched loadings, which render it quite efficient. See my answer [here](/a/36070727/1178314) for more details.
  Though with composite keys, you should map them as components for besting lazy loads. (Otherwise, accessing to one of the key property on an unloaded proxy will cause it to load.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. The bad thing here is that I believe I forgot to mention is that those two fields in question exist in the class that is named in the joined-class - SESProgramAssociation.

The problem is due to various standards in place for implementation, I cannot modify the SESProgramAssociation class to let's say remove those fields and generate a standalone class for that entity.

I have to somehow reuse the SESProgramAssociation, but only those two fields and relate that to the extension table....hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Then my third sentence is the way to go for you, use the `<join>` mapping inside `<joined-subclass name="SESProgramAssociationAggregate.SESProgramAssociation" ...>` for mapping you two other properties.

Comment: Gave that a try but got error, updated the OP. Link to complete mapping file which may help with debug: http://pastebin.com/ybSKHDsG

Comment: Choose between `true` or `false` for optional, but do not put both. This attribute let you tell NHibernate if it should not create any row in extension table in case all its related properties are `null` (`true` case). But your are right, I had tested `join` with my cases, which uses `subclass`, not `joined-subclass`. `subclass` allows specifying a `join`, but not `joined-subclass`. So you cannot do that, unless you have the possibility of extending base class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help and detailed input, I guess I need to find a different route.